# How to reload environmental variables in .profile using source for entire session?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables, .profile

So I need to reload my profile after making changes (this time due to a typo). I run `source ~/.profile` and everything works perfectly fine.

However the `source` command only applies to that terminal session. This means I'm running the command every time I open up a new terminal. I want to find a way to apply the `.profile`/environmental variables to the entire user session without logging out, not just the current terminal.

Is there a package or command that can execute this type of change by reloading the profile like it loaded on login?

**EDIT:**
To clarify that it is not a duplicate I don't want to use:

```
source ~/.profile
```

or

```
. ~/.profile
```

As they only effect changes on one terminal session. I want to effect changes across all started terminals from my user session. **I already have changes in the current terminal session using those commands**. I need them in newly opened terminal after I run the command (which to clarify I don't currently have. ***the changes are only effecting the current terminal*** and my question is to ***effect these changes across multiple terminals***

Comment: This will depend on your display manager, but this answer has an explanation of why it isn't possible usually, and specifically for the default Ubuntu display manager: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2949/how-do-i-tell-gnome-to-reread-my-profile

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. Environment variables are kept in each shell's per-process memory. Other processes (other shells, like the one you want to change eveything) cannot access this memory. Nor does `bash` listen to a socket for getting updates.

Reread `man bash`, especially the `INVOCATION` section.

`~/.profile` is more a `ksh` startup file. However, you could put `source $HOME/.profile` in your `~/.bashrc`.